# Дільничий чи дільничний?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

Здебільшого знаходжу на сайтах варіант "**дільничий**", зокрема і на сайті [Новокаховського техніко-економічного ліцею](https://nktel.jimdo.com/%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80/)

> Наш **дільничий** інспектор.

Такий варіант знаходжу й у [Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005.](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/40908/%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9):

> **дільничий** -чого, ч. Той хто обслуговує яку-небудь дільницю (напр., ***лікар***).

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/diljnychnyj) знаходжу лише такий варіант:

> **ДІЛЬНИ́ЧНИЙ**, а, е. Прикм. до дільниця 1. Надвечір до землянки на заболоченому коні під'їхав ***дільничний міліціонер*** (Михайло Стельмах, Правда.., 1961, 271).

Отож як правильно: ***дільничий*** чи ***дільничний***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Якщо ми говоримо про людину, яка обслуговує якусь певну територію (дільницю), то варто вживати похідний прикметник - "дільничний" (лікар, поліцейський тощо). Цитую "[Уроки державної мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/201.htm)":

> Дільницею називають адміністративно самостійний об’єкт, виробничий
>   вузол на будівництві, підприємстві, шахті, залізниці. Лексема входить
>   до словосполучення виборча дільниця, що позначає територію округу,
>   який об’єднує певну кількість виборців; приміщення, де працює
>   дільнична комісія під час виборчої кампанії. Є також складальна
>   дільниця, лікарська дільниця, дільниця народного суду тощо. **Похідне —
>   дільничний (а не дільничий). Дільничний міліціонер**.

Також за таким принципом потрібно казати "[дільничний інспектор](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97)" та "[дільничний пристав](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2)".

Comment: Наскільки я можу судити, майже жоден словник (окрім ВТССУМ) не визнає слова «дільничий» (без -н-); а Борис Рогоза навіть явно зауважує: «дільнич**н**ний (а не дільничий)». Але де-факто «дільничий» (без -н-) доволі широко вживається. Цікаво, чому так могло скластися. (Це не стосовно Вашої відповіді, це просто роздуми вголос.)

Comment: Погоджуюся, що питання про вживання слова "дільничий" є цікавим, однак, на жаль, не зміг знайти інформації, яка могла б пояснити чого воно є поширеним (адже виходить, що єдиним правильним варіантом є "дільничний"). Гугл також при вводі слова "дільничий" пропонує варіант "дільничний". Можливо, якщо вдасться знайти більше інформації, я доповню цю відповідь нею.

Answer (score -1):

На мою думку, форма "дільничий" (без Н) є більш притаманною живій мові, хоча б з огляду на спрощення приголосних, а "дільничНий" (з Н) - це рудимент русифікаторської політики радянського мовознавства. Тому посилання на "дільничНих" з творів радянських корифеїв не є доречним.

Comment: Цікаво, а *каплиця - капличний* це прийнятно?

Comment: Навряд чи це про русифікацію. Російською якраз без Н - участковый

Comment: @SerhiiKheilyk больничньій, граничньій.